# Unable to connect to Cloud SQL for SQL Server from Cloud Data Fusion

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I cannot to access to my private Cloud SQL for SQL Server instance from Data Fusion.

I read documentation and I followed all these steps:

1. created Cloud SQL for SQL Server instance with private IP on default network
2. created Data Fusion instance with private IP on default network
3. created peering connection between Data Fusion on default network
4. checked peering connection between Cloud SQL on default network
5. granted to SQL Client role to Data Fusion services account
6. created a firewall rule to allow traffic from Data Fusion private IP class to default network
7. installed sql server jdbc drivers on Data Fusion

I'm able to connect to Cloud SQL for SQL Server instance using its private IP from a vm instance bu I cannot connect to same instance from Data Fusion.

Data Fusion returns a timeout error.

```
Error: Connection timed out: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.
```

For MySQL and Postgres there are specific connectors for Cloud SQL but not for SQL Server.

There is someone that has successfully connected a Cloud SQL for SQL Server instance to Data Fusion by private ip?

Comment: Since the steps you followed to config the connection based on the GCP documentation, the issue may be specific case. I  recommend you to [open a support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases) in the Cloud Console which will allow the support to focus on investigation for your specific issue that may lead to this connection failure.

Comment: did you solve this issue? I think I can help

Comment: @jquinter I am also stuck at the same point. Is there any other solution you want to share.

Answer (score 1):

i try create Data Fusion in private ip and create VPC Peering to my VPC, but still can't acess CloudSQL in private IP, so im create vm haproxy with private IP for that

Data Fusion Private IP ---> Haproxy Private IP ---> CloudSQL Private IP

https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/create-private-ip